# Web Authentication Broker only returns Callback Url?

Tags: c#, windows-8, oauth

In my app I have the WebAuthenticationBroker working, but for some reason the ResponseData only returns the Callback Url and not the token, verifier, etc. Should that data be part of the Url that gets returned by the WAB? If so does that mean there is an issue with the providers API?

Here is my code

```
public async Task<string> Authorize(string oAuthAuthorizeUrl)
{
    System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(oAuthAuthorizeUrl);
    System.Uri EndUri = new Uri("https://api.xyz.com/oauth/authorize-submit");
    //System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString());

    var auth =
        await
        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, StartUri, EndUri);

    var responseText = auth.ResponseData; // Callback url specified above gets returned here
    ...
}
```

The API uses  OAuth 1.0a. Thanks for the help.